# I get subscript out of range error when selecting sheets in an array

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime-error, subscript

I'm getting a run-time error '9': subscript out of range on **ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(myArr()).Select** line. Please help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()                                                      

Dim sH As Worksheet                                                             
Dim Assy As String
Dim Path As String
Dim ShName As String
Dim myArr() As Variant
Dim X As Integer

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then                                                      Worksheets("Supplier PDFs").Activate                                        'make Supplier PDFs sheet active sheet
    Assy = Range("C5").Text                                                     'Assembly name
    Path = Range("H5").Text                                                     'Directory path name
    If Assy = "" Or Path = "" Then                                              'If name or folder path is empty,
        MsgBox "An entry was left blank! Please provide name and/or filepath."  'Give error message
        End
    Else
    End If

    For Each sH In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets                                    'for each worksheet
        ReDim myArr(X)                                                          'redeclare matrix myArr with size X
        sH.Activate                                                             'activate sheet
        ShName = ActiveSheet.Name                                               'ShName is the name of the active sheet
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1                                'Set page width to 1-page
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape                         'Set orientation to landscape
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Draft = False                                     'Print with graphics
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter                         'Set paper size to letter

        If Range("F3") = Assy And ActiveSheet.Visible = True Then               'if assembly level is right,
            myArr(X) = ShName                                                   'update array element with sheet name
            X = X + 1                                                           'index counter X
        Else                                                                    'if not, do nothing
        End If
    Next sH                                                                     'end for loop


    ReDim Preserve myArr(X)                                                     'reset myArr array size to 0
    **ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(myArr()).Select**                                                      'select all sheets with sheetnames in myArr
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$R$26"                              'Set print area to sheet limits
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    Path & Assy & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True                                                      'Set filename, quality, properties and open after publish
                                                                                'reset myArr size to zero

    If X > 0 Then
        X = X - 1
    Else
    End If

    ReDim myArr(0)
End If

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: when it errors, look at what is stored in `myArr`.  You will find that all but the last item is blank.  Since there is no sheet with a blank name you will not find it and the error will be produced.  Look into RedimPreserve().

Comment: You will also want that inside the IF so you are not creating blanks in your array.

Comment: `myArr()` doesn't have an index specified. You ***should*** be getting a run-time error 438.